# Field Validation Error - TExt Danger is coming up true, when text field is populated

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

SO everything is going great with creating my registration page but when I added in passsword and confirm password and tested it, I ended up getting the password field left blank error mmessage, even though I am populating the text field and meeting password requirements.

I have no idea why this is happening.  What part of my MVC 5 program would be causing this to be true?

Here is my controller:

```
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "MerchantID,MerchantName,State,City,StreetAddress,zip,phoneNumber,email, website")] Merchant merchant)
{

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        var UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(_context));
        //code that I am trying to implement to add to merhcant role
        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = merchant.MerchantName, Email = merchant.email };
        var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, merchant.Password);
        //Above code is from Register controller


        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            await this.UserManager.AddToRoleAsync("MerchantID", "Merchant");
            var code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
            var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
            await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking this link: <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">link</a>");
            ViewBag.Link = callbackUrl;
            return View("DisplayEmail");

        }

        AddErrors(result);

            //ASP.Net provided code, don't touch.
            db.Merchants.Add(merchant);

            db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }


    return View(merchant);
}
```

Here is the View:

```
    <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the Model:

```
     [Required]
[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Display(Name = "Password")]
public string Password { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
[Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
```

Comment: When you step through your controller, is the password property in your `Merchant` VM populated?

Comment: Sorry I am kind of new to this.  What is VM?

Comment: View Model - the model that is passed to the view.

Comment: Ok I fixed it.  My Password and ConfirmPassowrd was not being passed to my controller.